# POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/ 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: axios, bad-request

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2RJXTtCn2Y&t=1316s) verbatim.
The following code throws up a 400 Bad Request error, with the following information:

> data: undefined status: undefined statusText: undefined headers:
> undefined config: undefined request: undefined

**Code**

```js
if (!this.errors.length) {
  const formData = {
    username: this.username,
    password: this.password1,
  };
  console.log(formData);

  axios.post("/api/v1/users/", formData);
}
```

Console.log prints the following, so there's no issue with the data:

> {username: 'code@code.com', password: 'code'}

A bit surprised as I've set up CORS and djoser exactly as in the tutorial.
This is the relevant code in urls.py:

```js
urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

  path('api/v1/', include('djoser.urls')),
  path('api/v1/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
]
```

I'm able to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/` and view and post via my browser, so the issue must be with axios, but I'm not sure what it is. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the actual response from the server? Try adding `.catch((err) => console.error(err.toJSON()))` for a clearer picture of what's going wrong. Could you also please [edit] your question to include the server route handler for `POST /api/v1/users`

Comment: I realised that I'm getting this error when I input (dummy) passwords that are either short (e.g., 4 letters) or look too similar to the username input. For example, "something@something.com" with password "something" will throw up this error (see below), but more sophisticated passwords won't. I'm surprised the server responds this way, is there a way for me to catch this error (or change server settings to allow more flexibility in passwords)?

```{message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', description: undefined, number: undefined, fileName: undefined, …}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that I'm getting this error when I input (dummy) passwords that are either short (e.g., 4 letters) or look too similar to the username input. For example, "something@something.com" with password "something" will throw up this error, but more sophisticated passwords won't.